# Data Extraction - Can this Regex be made better?

Tags: c, regex, gnu

I have a C program that is decoding data from an APRSIS server. It's working fine on a GNU/LINUX machine.

I have created this regular expression for extracting weather data. It's long. Here is a sample data record and the regex:

**Data Record**

```
KG7FOQ-13>APTT4,HARIN,WIDE1*,WIDE21,qAO,WEBER:!4227.10N/11422.32W_217/010g015t047r000p000P025h76b10078TU2k
WA6MHA-11>APOTW1,WIDE1-1,WIDE2-1,qAR,N6LXX-10:!3410.50N/11828.90W_182/009g012t070P000h30b10220V126OTW1
KM6AHX-12>APOTU0,N6EX-5,qAR,N6LXX-10:!3411.20N/11813.02W_264/002g010t062p001h61T2WX
KM6AHX-12>APOTU0,N6EX-1*,qAR,VINCNT:!3411.20N/11813.02W_189/010g008t061p001h59T2WX
WA6MHA-11>APOTW1,WIDE1-1,WIDE2-1,qAR,K6LOT-10:!3410.50N/11828.90W_127/008g014t070P000h30b10220V127OTW1
K6OUA-11>APOTW1,WA6ZSN,WIDE2,qAR,N6LXX-10:!3417.39N/11849.36W_225/003g005t066V133P000h45b10138OTW1
KM6AHX-12>APOTU0,N6EX-1*,qAR,VINCNT:!3411.20N/11813.02W_234/005g008t060p001h59T2WX
AD6NH>APJYC1,TCPIP*,qAC,T2CAWEST:=3352.28N/11749.75W_000/000t065h48b10206 /A=259 https://www.ka2ddo.org/ka2ddo/YAAC.html
KM6AHX-12>APOTU0,N6EX-1*,qAR,VINCNT:!3411.20N/11813.02W_170/004g013t060p001h60T2WX
WA6MHA-11>APOTW1,WIDE1-1,WIDE2-1,qAR,N6LXX-10:!3410.50N/11828.90W_120/005g012t069P000h30b10220V127OTW1
K9COE-11>APOTW1,W6SCE-10,qAR,N6LXX-10:!3414.63N/11846.70W_105/007g007t065P035h51b10191OTW1
KM6AHX-12>APOTU0,N6EX-5*,qAR,K6LOT-10:!3411.20N/11813.02W_002/001g013t060p001h60T2WX
KM6AHX-12>APOTU0,N6EX-1*,qAR,VINCNT:!3411.20N/11813.02W_358/003g013t060p001h60T2WX
WA6MHA-11>APOTW1,WIDE1-1,WIDE2-1,qAR,K6LOT-10:!3410.50N/11828.90W_115/004g013t069P000h30b10220V126OTW1
```

**Regex**

```
":[!=][0-9.NS]*/[0-9.EW]*_([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{3})([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?"
    "([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?"
    "([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?"
    "([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?"
    "([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?"
    "([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})?.*$"
```

A given data record may not contain all possible data types ([tphbcsLls#grPV]) nor is the order guaranteed.

Is there a better way to do this? It seems a bit brute force.

Chuck Bland

Comment: In regards to the `x123` patterns, do you simply need to validate all? Capture all together in a single capture group? Have separate capture groups for each?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question, the first three patterns are there just to make sure I'm a parsing the correct type of record from the stream. There are many different types that are possible. Everything else in the capture groups I want separate, parsed out of the record for processing.

Comment: Could you add more sample records?

Comment: By `x123` I meant one of the `([tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})` patterns

Comment: @PeterThoeny - separate capture groups for each. This is the data captured by the x123 groups: g015t047r000p000P025h76b10078. I want the result to be g015, t047, r000, etc. I have to allow that any of the possible data groups could appear, in any order, even if I only process a few of them.

Comment: @KristofNeirynck - working on it

Comment: @KristofNeirynck - Data added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split up the parsing into two steps:

1. validate string, and group all `x123` type patterns into a single capture group
2. split all `x123` type patterns into separate capture groups

**Step 1:**

```
":[!=][0-9.NS]*\/[0-9.EW]*_([0-9]{3})\/([0-9]{3})((?:[tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})+)"
```

Explanation of regex:

- `:[!=][0-9.NS]*\/[0-9.EW]*_` - expected pattern to pick correct type of record
- `([0-9]{3})` - capture group 1
- `\/` - slash
- `([0-9]{3})` - capture group 2
- `(` - capture group 3 start

  - `(?:` - non-capture group start

    - `[tphbcsLls#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5}` - expected pattern (to be repeated)
  - `)+` - non-capture group end, repeat this 1+ times
- `)` - capture group 3 end

Resulting capture groups for input `KG7FOQ-13>APTT4,HARIN,WIDE1*,WIDE21,qAO,WEBER:!4227.10N/11422.32W_217/010g015t047r000p000P025h76b10078TU2k`:

- `"217"` - capture group 1
- `"010"` - capture group 2
- `"g015t047r000p000P025h76b10078"` - capture group 3

**Step 2:** Now take the result of capture group 3 and split it:

```
"(?=[tphbcsLls#grPV])"
```

Explanation of split regex:

- `(?=` - positive lookahead for:
- `[tphbcsLls#grPV]` - one of these chars
- `)` - end positive lookahead

Result of split:

- `["g015", "t047", "r000", "p000", "P025", "h76", "b10078"]`

**EDIT:** After learning that positive lookahad is not available: Instead of a `split` you can use a `match` with global flag to get the array of items:

```
/[tphbcsLls#grPV][^tphbcsLls#grPV]*/g
```

Explanation of match regex:

- `[tphbcsLls#grPV]` - scan for start letter
- `[^tphbcsLls#grPV]*` - grab all letters that are *not* the start letter
- rinse & repeat with the `g` global flag

Result of split:

- `["g015", "t047", "r000", "p000", "P025", "h76", "b10078"]`

Comment: Wow. I like this!

Comment: I have no issues with accepting the answer. Have been waiting to see if any other responses come in. I am coding your solution now.

Comment: I was afraid this might happen. GNU does not support lookahead.

Comment: @ChuckBland: See EDIT for a way without lookahead.

Comment: The two responses are very close, in terms of approach. Neither are complete since the system I'm using GNU/Linux doesn't not implement all the regex features used in Peter's C solution and I'm not using Java used in Kristof's solution. But they both answer the question "Is there a better way" and that answer is clearly yes (as expected) and they give some direction on how to implement a better solution in situation.

Ultimately choose Peter's as it is the closest to what I can do and it is in C.

Thanks to both responders.

Comment: @ChuckBland: Out of curiosity for step 2, did the match with `g` flag work?

Comment: Peter, I'm a college prof and didn't get time in the last day or so to follow-up on this. I do want to give you FB. I'll try to get to it soon as I'd love to understand what it's doing too. This is part of an assignment for next term.  :-)

Comment: POSIX also does not support non-capturing groups.  :-(

I'm still playing with your split approach. Comments are welcome.

Comment: This is what I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with, based on Peter Thoeney's input.

```
// gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o RME RME.c && ./RME
// Source: https://gist.github.com/ianmackinnon/3294587

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define    NUMBER_OF_GROUPS     4 //groups in your regex + 1
#define    NUMBER_OF_WX_GROUPS 14

char    WXsource[64];
char    source[] = "KG7FOQ-13>APTT4,HARIN,WIDE1*,WIDE2-1,qAO,WEBER"
                  ":!4227.10N/11422.32W_217/010g015t047r000p000P025h76b10078TU2k";

char    *regexString1 = ":[!=][0-9.NS]*.[0-9.EW]*_([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{3})([tphbcsLls#grPV0-9 .]+).{4}$";
char    *regexString2 = "([tphbcsLls#grPV][^tphbcsLls#grPV]*)";
char    WXDataArray[NUMBER_OF_WX_GROUPS][16];
int     numberDecodedGroups=0;
int     sourceOffset=0;
int     start;
int     count;

regex_t     regexCompiled1;
regex_t     regexCompiled2;
regmatch_t  groupArray[NUMBER_OF_GROUPS];

int main ()
    {
    //the first regex matches the coords, wind data,
    //the entire string of weather data, and weather station ID.
    //It captures the wind data and weather data.
    if (regcomp(&regexCompiled1, regexString1, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE))
        {
        printf("Could not compile regular expression 1.\n");
        return(1);
        }

    //The second regex parses the weather data into the individual
    //items. It requires multiple calls to accomplish the process.
    if (regcomp(&regexCompiled2, regexString2, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE))
        {
        printf("Could not compile regular expression 2.\n");
        return(1);
        }

    //first extraction. The weather data is in group 3.
    regexec(&regexCompiled1, source, NUMBER_OF_GROUPS, groupArray, 0);

    start = groupArray[3].rm_so;                //start of weather data
    count = groupArray[3].rm_eo-start;          //bytes of weather data

    //create a null terminated string of the weather data
    memcpy(&WXsource[0], &source[start], count);
    WXsource[count]=0;

    //this loop iterates for each entry in the weather data. With each loop
    //the starting point is incremented by the length of the data just
    //extracted. Each string is null terminated in an array.
    //the regex looks for a character of one the field identifiers followed
    //by as many characters it can grab that are NOT field identifiers.
    for(int matchIndex=0; matchIndex < NUMBER_OF_WX_GROUPS; matchIndex++)
        {
        //find the data item. sourceOffset moves the beginning of the source
        //string by the size of the previous extracted data item.
        if (regexec(&regexCompiled2, &WXsource[sourceOffset], NUMBER_OF_GROUPS, groupArray, 0))
            break;

        //start of entry. SHould always be 0
        start = groupArray[1].rm_so;

        //eo ends up being the count.
        count = groupArray[1].rm_eo;

        //copy the sub-string to the output array
        memcpy(&WXDataArray[matchIndex][0], &WXsource[sourceOffset], count);

        //add the null termination
        WXDataArray[matchIndex][count]=0;

        //increment sourceOffset
        sourceOffset += groupArray[1].rm_eo;

        //increment the number of fields extracted
        numberDecodedGroups++;
        }

    for(int Index = 0; Index < numberDecodedGroups; Index++)
        printf("%s\n", &WXDataArray[Index][0]);

    return(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer resembles Peter's.
First extract the "data" as one long string, then find all sub-data within.

I've implemented it in java.

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class So66537099 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] lines = (
                "KG7FOQ-13>APTT4,HARIN,WIDE1*,WIDE21,qAO,WEBER:!4227.10N/11422.32W_217/010g015t047r000p000P025h76b10078TU2k\n" +
                "..."
        ).split("\n");

        final Pattern PATTERN1 = Pattern.compile(".*?:[!=][0-9.NS]*/[0-9.EW]*_([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{3})((?:[tphbcsLl#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5})*).*?");
        final Pattern PATTERN2 = Pattern.compile("[tphbcsLl#grPV][0-9 .]{2,5}");
        for (final String line : lines) {
            System.out.println("line = " + line);
            final Matcher m1 = PATTERN1.matcher(line);
            if (m1.matches()) {
                System.out.println("matches");
                System.out.println("m1.group(1) = " + m1.group(1));
                System.out.println("m1.group(2) = " + m1.group(2));
                final String data = m1.group(3);
                System.out.println("m1.group(3) = " + data);
                if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                    final Matcher m2 = PATTERN2.matcher(data);
                    while (m2.find()) {
                        System.out.println("... m2.group() = " + m2.group());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("doesn't match");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output:

```
line = KG7FOQ-13>APTT4,HARIN,WIDE1*,WIDE21,qAO,WEBER:!4227.10N/11422.32W_217/010g015t047r000p000P025h76b10078TU2k
matches
m1.group(1) = 217
m1.group(2) = 010
m1.group(3) = g015t047r000p000P025h76b10078
... m2.group() = g015
... m2.group() = t047
... m2.group() = r000
... m2.group() = p000
... m2.group() = P025
... m2.group() = h76
... m2.group() = b10078
...
```